# A migration in a rails 3 app that will increase the value of an integer field by +1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to write a migration that will increase the value of an integer field by +1. I've tried several variations and done searches. What I am looking for is something like:

```
def self.up
   User.update_all(:category => [:category + 1])
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will do it

```
User.update_all("category = (category + 1)")
```